# Making a new variable column using if/else statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset that contains a column of the state in which a particular office is located.  I would like to take that column and make a new column denoting which region of the US that office is located.  The state column has the postal abbreviations for each state (ie. NY stands for New York) and I am using the US Census Bureau's Regions.

Here's a mock example of the data.  I don't have a Region column, but I want to create it:

```
Store    State    Region
A        FL       South
B        NY       Northeast
C        CA       West
D        IL       Midwest
E        MA       Northeast
```

Let's make it simpler and let's just say I want to denote only offices in the Northeast.  I used the following syntax:

```
stores$Northeast<-if(
        stores$state=="ME"|"NH"|"VT"|"MA"|"RI"|"CT"|"NY"|"PA"|"NJ"){
print("Northeast")
} else{print("Non-northeast")
}
```

but I get an error message saying that the | operation doesn't work on characters.  Is there a different function I should be using instead?

Comment: Beware of requiring a specific method for your desired solution.  As the Data-Munger Guru says, "Tell me what you want to do, not how you want to do it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting in the interest of saving people's typing time. There are already two vectors available as part of the base R installation that can be used to do this very efficiently: `state.abb` and `state.region`.  If you have a named vector it can be indexed via the names as a look-up facility. They both need to be converted from factor to character (and  the index needs to be de-factorized as well):

```
# Do read `?states`. Hey, S was invented in the US, but why not some Yuropean constants?
 mock <-read.table(text="Store    State    
 A        FL      
 B        NY      
 C        CA      
 D        IL      
 E        MA      ",head=TRUE)
 stat <- as.character(state.region)
 > names(stat) <- as.character(state.abb)

> mock$Region  <- stat[as.character(mock$State)]
> mock
  Store State        Region
1     A    FL         South
2     B    NY     Northeast
3     C    CA          West
4     D    IL North Central
5     E    MA     Northeast
```

If you want to "edit" the regional assignments, do this:

```
> stat["IL"] <- "Midwest"
> mock$Region  <- stat[as.character(mock$State)]
> mock
  Store State    Region
1     A    FL     South
2     B    NY Northeast
3     C    CA      West
4     D    IL   Midwest
5     E    MA Northeast
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the `%in%` operator here:

```
NE = c("ME","NH","VT","MA","RI","CT","NY","PA","NJ")

if stores$state %in% NE {
    print("Northeast")
} else {
    print("Non-northeast")
}
```

You can also define a new variable this way, especially if you are going to go on to define other regions:

```
stores$region = "Non-northeast"
stores$region[stores$state %in% NE] = "Northeast"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `%in%` operator!

```
stores$Northeast <- ifelse(stores$state %in% c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "RI", "CT", "NY", "PA", "NJ"), "Northeast", "Non-northeast")
```

cheers

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me an error message.  It just codes everything as "Non-northeast".  This is the warning message:  Warning message:
In if (crime06_07$State %in% c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "RI", "CT",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: It's rather painful to use `ifelse` construction when there are several catergoires to test for. The use of `match` or named vectors will be faster and easier to maintain.